# ODI KM Option - value from FLEX FIELD

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

Do you think that it's possible to take a value into an ODI IKM Option (for example) from a flexfield?
Example:
You define a flex field on the target table and then pass the value in the IKM.
Then, reading the variable, it's possible to pass it to an option from the IKM?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found that it's not possible to do it. Conditional Expression can take predefined values. You can find in the next all the combinations:

> Condition Expression – It allows you to set the required condition for
>   the selected option. Double-click the field for editing the condition
>   expression for the selected option. Click the browse icon Browse icon,
>   to launch the Edit Expression Editor, which enables you to create or
>   edit the existing groovy script that determines whether a knowledge
>   module should be enabled, disabled, displayed or hidden.
>
> Examples are:
>
> return
>   options.getValue("Cache").equals("true")?"show=true,enable=true":"show=false,enable=false";
>
> This looks at the value of another KM Option called "Cache". If its
>   value is "false," then the KM Option is hidden, because it's not
>   relevant.
>
> return
>   (isStreaming)?"show=false,enable=false":"show=true,enable=true";
>
> This looks at the Mapping isStreaming property. If it's true, then
>   this option is hidden.
>
> **[source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odidg/using-component-kms.html#GUID-188EC8DE-82EF-4460-889A-B8FAAAD07A0B)**

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do.

1. You may use `odiRef.getTable(java.lang.String pProperty)` in the code of your IKM. One of possible values for `pProperty` is the code of your FlexField.
2. If you like to pass if through the option just pas `<?…?>`-substitution as a value of the option. (Probable you should play with `%-` or `?-`substitutions, which is working.)

Refer to «Substitution API Reference» on Oracle site. Many functions like `getTable`, `getIndex`, `getAK`, `getContext` and others can obtain flexField value of an object of the corresponding type.

Additionally there is the `odiRef.getFlexFieldValue()` method. It gets the value of any object of any type, but it is required to pass internal IDs as an argument. So it is not convenient.

Comment: Hi, maybe I wasn't so clear in the question, but in the title I was. I need to take a value from a flex field, direcly into the ODI KM **OPTION**, not in the KM itself.

Comment: See 2. «…If you like `to pass if through the option` just pas <?…?>-substitution as a value of the option.…»